# How to set button image depend on array's value with for-loop?

Tags: swift

I have array like this, and it's count is not fixed

```
var option = ["0","1","0","1","1","0","0"]
```

With a button array

```
var buttons = [firstBtn,secondBtn,thirdBtn]
```

I need to set button image depend on option array value

```
option[0] = "0", firstBtn.setImage(zeroImage, for: .normal)
option[0] = "1", firstBtn.setImage(firstImage, for: .normal)
```

I have tried below

```
for button in buttons { 
        for value in option {
              if value == "0" {
                    button?.setImage(zeroImage, for: .normal)
              }else {
                    button?.setImage(firstImage, for: .normal)
              }
            }
          }
```

But it may cause inside for-loop will continuously get next until it finished, and back to outside for-loop

I need any button has own image

Additionally my option's count is not fixed

it should depend on how many buttons I have

How should I fix my problem ?

Comment: for I in 0..buttons.count { button?.setimage(option[I] == 0 ? zeroImage: firstImage, for: .normal)}

Comment: Use button collection and get image from option using button tags.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create button collection like below

```
@IBOutlet var buttonsCollection: [UIButton]!    // set tags for button on storyboard or xib or assign programmatically if creating button programatically
```

create array of image named length equal to buttonsCollection

```
var option = ["0","1","0","1","1","0","0"]
```

and then simply use for each loop

```
for button in buttonsCollection {
                button?.setImage(option[button.tag], for: .normal)
      }
```

**OR** if we go with your implementation

```
var option = ["0","1","0","1","1","0","0"] // make sure option array should be greatert than or equal to buttons array
 // set tags for button on storyboard or xib or assign programmatically if creating button programatically

var buttons = [firstBtn,secondBtn,thirdBtn]       
for button in buttons {
        button?.setImage(option[button.tag], for: .normal) 
          }
```

***Note: for both cases make sure to set same index for button and its title in both arrays***